# PHP/SQLite: Delete Cookie (Refresh Error)

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I have a simple PHP page to run when the user wants to sign out of my site. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    setcookie("session", "", time()-3600);
    header("location:signin.php");
?>
```

My problem is, whenever I link to this code, the server says that the page can't be found, but when I refresh it "suddenly" finds the page. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

location probably wants a fully qualified url, http://whatever.com/signin.php should work